# Powershell in Invoking web request

Tags: xml, powershell

I am still new to powershell and i am creating a script for automation. 
I created a script that would run all of the needed functions, However
when it tries to run a certain function it generates an error. I tried to remove the function that generates an error and run it on the terminal to my surprise it works normally it does'nt work when i try to insert it in my script and always generate an error

Here is the function that generates an error
"Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

```
function Create-SUMStartPayload{
[xml]$REST = '<Process xmlns="http://www.sap.com/lmsl/slp">
<parameters>
<Parameter>
<id>UiTopology</id>        
<value>JAVA_ONLY</value>    
</Parameter>
</parameters>
</Process>'
return $REST
}

function Start-SUMStartPayload{
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[xml]$SUMXML)
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://j3lsap.nestle.com:1128/lmsl/sumjava/J3L/slp/services/SUM4Java/processes" -Method post -ContentType 'text/xml' -Body $SUMXML -Credential $j3ladm
 }
```

I dont know what is causing the error. it only occurs when i insert this functions into my script

Answer (score 0):

Does it generate an error when the function is called, or when it is declared? Paste in the actual script and especially the actual error text which includes line number, etc.